# Load testing SharePoint 2013 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

When attempting to load test SharePoint I am getting over 2000 `Exception   SocketException An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` When running a load test that just hits the main page of our SharePoint site and nothing else. We thought this could have been due to the load balancer that we had on the environment but even after removing that from the equation still the same issue. I am new to load testing SharePoint so any advice would be greatly appreciated as my google searches have not turned up anything useful. We have also attempted to load test using HP's Loadrunner and after 4 virtual users connect to the server the rest get the connection reset error. In load runner we have even tried to set it to spoof IP addresses and use unique users for each test with same results.

Bill

Answer (score 0):

here is one response from MSFT:

This error message may be caused by the connection problem with SQL. You can try the method below:
Upgrade the NIC to the latest drivers and then disable the following NIC card settings:
(Before you change the registry values please do a backup)

In registry editor browse to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
Change the following keys to '0' 'decimal'
EnableTCPA
EnableRSS
EnableTCPChimney
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c308b274-54f9-44f6-84cb-6d205bd6e356/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Comment: My NIC was up to date and when I went to that path in regedit none of those parameters existed.

Comment: My NIC was up to date with the latest drivers and when I went into regedit those parameters didn't exits.